# Elastic/Kibana group and average by multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I have an elastic document Action(task_id, username, time_spent_seconds, action_start_time, action_end_time, action_type). How can i create a kibana visualization to show the top average(per task) times of users. Currently i have a pie chart that is sliced by username, and sized by average(time_spent_seconds). But this is the average per Action and not per task. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did this by sizing with formula `sum(time_spent_seconds) / unique_count(task_id)`